# Access Query: Use user input to select column for query in sql

Tags: sql, ms-access, user-controls, parameter-passing, iif

I'm new to ACCESS and SQL. My apologies if I misuse some of the references and terms. I'm trying to use user input to select a field in my table and then filter the data in that field based on user criteria.

I have a table `Emissions_Units` with many columns and I want to make a nice form for the user to select a pollutant (which is a column in my table) and then select criteria to apply to that pollutant (i.e. column in table). Pollutants or columns in the table include `CO_Emissions`, `NO2_Emissions`, `PM_Emissions`.

Then, once the column is selected, I want to filter that column based on the user max and min criteria. Then have the query present the results.

I included some SQL code that I've been working on that doesn't work but may show what I'm trying to do. I also tried `SWITCH` instead of `IIF`. If this is possible, I would then like to also grab information from other columns from that table that match the rows from the query. For instance, I'd like to pull the information from the Name and Location columns that are associated with the rows that meet the user input results.

```
PARAMETERS [Enter Pollutant to Review (CO, NO2, PM):] Text, [Enter Maximum Emissions (0.00 g/s):] Number, [Enter Minimum Emissions (0.00 g/s):] Number;

SELECT
    IIF([Enter Pollutant to Review (CO, NO2, PM):] = "CO", Emissions_Units.CO_Emissions AS CalcValues,
    IIF([Enter Pollutant to Review (CO, NO2, PM):] = "NO2", Emissions_Units.NO2_Emissions AS CalcValues,
    IIF([Enter Pollutant to Review (CO, NO2, PM):] = "PM", Emissions_Units.PM_Emissions AS CalcValues, 'Retry' )
  )
)
FROM Emissions_Units
WHERE CalcValues >= [Enter Minimum Emissions (0.00 g/s)] 
  AND CalcValues <= [Enter Maximum Emissions (0.00 g/s)];
```

Comment: Normalize table structure and your life will be much simpler. Have a single field for EmissionData and another field for EmissionType. Apply filter on EmissionType field. Edit question to show sample data as text table.

Comment: Thanks June7. I understand but I think it will be too difficult to change the table/dataset so I was hoping for an alternative. I hope you can help and suggest some other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query works:

```
PARAMETERS [Enter Pollutant to Review (CO, NO2, PM):] Text, [Enter Minimum Emissions in gps] Number, [Enter Maximum Emissions in gps] Number;

SELECT *, Switch([Enter Pollutant to Review (CO, NO2, PM):] = "CO", Emissions_Units.CO_Emissions,
  [Enter Pollutant to Review (CO, NO2, PM):] = "NO2", Emissions_Units.NO2_Emissions,
  [Enter Pollutant to Review (CO, NO2, PM):] = "PM", Emissions_Units.PM_Emissions) AS CalcValues
 
FROM Emissions_Units

WHERE Switch([Enter Pollutant to Review (CO, NO2, PM):] = "CO", Emissions_Units.CO_Emissions,
  [Enter Pollutant to Review (CO, NO2, PM):] = "NO2", Emissions_Units.NO2_Emissions,
  [Enter Pollutant to Review (CO, NO2, PM):] = "PM", Emissions_Units.PM_Emissions)

BETWEEN [Enter Minimum Emissions in gps] AND [Enter Maximum Emissions in gps];
```

PARAMETERS clause didn't like the 0.00 so I reworded the prompts. However, instead of popup prompt in query, reference controls on form for user input.

Comment: Thanks June7 but the recommendation didn't get me the results I'm looking for, which may be because I need to add more details. My apologies. I've attempted to add more details to see if you could provide another option. When I start the query, my 3 parameters get asked but then addition questions are ask, including "Enter Parameter Value ? Emissions_Units.NO2_Emissions" through ..."Enter Parameter Value ? Emissions_Units.PM_Emissions". But I want the questions to stop after "Enter Max..." Then use selection to complete query, where the Switch is supposed to be equivalent to if-then statements

Comment: Suggested query works for me. I get 3 prompts only. Edit question to show sample data and desired output as text tables. Your attempted IIf() is not valid in query. Alias field name cannot be within the conditional expression. Another approach would involve a UNION query.

Comment: I got it to work, yay! I ended up having a typo in the SELECT SWITCH section. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Thanks again, June7. What would be the best method (SQL code) to add another table to this query so I can provide additional details to the results of the user input. For instance, the other table (Unit_Information) includes location information with columns titled "Address" and "State" that I would like to connect to the results from the query you helped me with. I have already added a Relationship to these two tables, if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: Related how - what fields? Could just include the other table in this query. Use Access query designer to assist. As suggested, provide sample data. Edit your question or start another one.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks again for your help and time June7!